# jquery opening one section at once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am currently working on laravel 5.2.I am trying to make a comment section for each post.Here's my blade view,
`

```
<div class="row">
    <section class="col-md-12"> 
        @foreach($storages as $storage)
        @if($storage->post_id==$post->id) 
        <div id="jumbo3" class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row" id="rlr">
                <section class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2">
                    <img  id="imagesize8" class="img-circle" src="/src/uploads/avatars/{{$storage->user->avatar}}"/>
                </section>
                <section class="col-md-3">
                    <a id="user10" href=""><h5 id="h52">{{$storage->user->getNameOrUsername() }}</h5></a>
                </section>
                <section class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-3">
                    <span id="rmvsgn1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>

                </section>
            </div>
            @if($storage->comment==0)
            <div class="row">
                {{ $storage->textcomment}}
            </div>
            @endif
            @if($storage->textcomment==0)
            <div class="row">
                <img src="{{$storage->comment}}"/>
            </div>
            @endif

            @endif
            @endforeach
    </section>
    </div>
    <button class="see-more">See Comments</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    @endif
    @endforeach
```

I am trying to display the comments by clicking on the comment section,here's my jquery,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.jumbotron').hide('.jumbotron');
        $('.see-more').click(function () {
            $('.jumbotron').toggle('.jumbotron');
        });
    });
</script>
```

but every time I am trying to get it for one section,it opens up for all posts.

Comment: for togle  $('.jumbotron').toggle('.jumbotron'); , u need to make ur selector more specific

Comment: i tried $(this),but it does not return anything

Comment: where exactly is the see-more class in ur html, u did not mention anywhere in ur code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".see-more").click(function(){
   $(this).prev( ".content" ).toggle();
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div class="article">
  <div class="content">
   Content 1
  </div>
  <button class="see-more">
  See more
  </button>
</div><div class="article">
  <div class="content">
   Content 2
  </div>
  <button class="see-more">
  See more
  </button>
</div><div class="article">
  <div class="content">
   Content 3
  </div>
  <button class="see-more">
  See more
  </button>
</div><div class="article">
  <div class="content">
   Content 4
  </div>
  <button class="see-more">
  See more
  </button>
</div><div class="article">
  <div class="content">
   Content 5
  </div>
  <button class="see-more">
  See more
  </button>
</div>
<div class="article">
  <div class="content">
   Content 6
  </div>
  <button class="see-more">
  See more
  </button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: doing this,when i am clicking the button nothing is opening.

Comment: @prabal.t - try `$('.jumbotron').toggle()` instead. `.see-more` isn't a child of `.jumbotron` in your code so that's why it's not working.

Comment: @cristian-if i am putting the see more class inside the jumbotron div,the see more button itself is hiding when clicked and is still toggling  for all the posts.How do i get a see more button where it works for posts individually??

Comment: put it just after the </div> of jumbotron

Comment: i did it already.it still does not work for individual posts.Whenever i click on any of the see more button of any of the posts,the comment section opens up..

Comment: for all the posts

Comment: Look at the code snippet i have posted, that should work for you

Comment: Yeah you can then addapt it to your project